# Google Cloud Vertex AI AutoML REST API Calls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I have trained a model with AutoML with google cloud. I am currently working on a website POC Test, that take user inputs for each factor, I will connect to the trained model API and output a prediction. 
Everything is written in `html` and `javascript` with `ajax` to make the API Calls.

I am facing problems with connecting the web to make valid REST API Calls.

To Clarify, I am finishing the whole API call and display result directly on the user's website.
Due to resources issue, I am not allowed to write a backend server handling the metadata.

Here is a snippet of the code. Credentials are masked.

```js
   const PROJECT_ID    = "ProjectID" ;
   const ENDPOINT_ID   = "ENDPOINTID" ;
   const ACCESS_TOKEN  = "PRINTED FROM GCLOUD-AUTH-PRINT-ACCESS-TOKEN IN SHELL" ;
   const ENDPOINTURL   = `https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/endpoints/${ENDPOINT_ID}:predict` ;
```

Below is my ajax call:

```js
$.ajax(
{
    type : "POST",
    url  :  ENDPOINTURL, 
    headers: 
    {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    data: JSON.stringify(INPUT_DATA),
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data)
    {
        handlePredictionResults(data);
    },

    error :function(xhr, status, error) 
    {
        
        try 
        {
            console.log("An error occurred:", error);

        } catch (e) 
        {
            console.log("An error occurred:", e);
        }
    }
});
```

I have been receiving two error code `401` and `404` upon inspecting the browser preview.
Which I know should indicate that I have authorisation issues and resource loading issues.

I wonder if I should use a Service Account / OAuth 2.0 token for connecting, but I do not see that inside the CURL REST API Request command on the console when I trained the model.

Comment: Where are you running this code? If in the user's web browser, you have two choices. Use user OAuth or write a backend to perform the actual REST calls and use a service account. If you running this code in a backend, use the metadata service to fetch credentials from the attached service account. Edit your post and cleary define how the code is running and from where.

Comment: Edited the question. To clarify, I am running the whole form submission, API call, result display on the user's website with a button click. 
I am not allowed to write a backend, which is more familiar to me. 

@JohnHanley

Comment: OK - I know what you mean, but your code is not running on a website. The code is running (executing) in the browser. That distinction is very important. Since you cannot write a backend, you must use Google user OAuth. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow Suggestion: talk to whoever told you that you cannot write a backend. That is not the best decision. You will have a much easier development time writing backend code. You will have a much easier time getting your application approved by Google to use those APIs.

Comment: Give the other person this [document](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en) to read. Then convince that person that writing a backend that uses service accounts for authorization is the better decision. Then you can write a nice clean web browser GUI that talks to your backend.

Comment: I totally agree that a backend should be used to take in the request. 
Happy to have a fellow that understands the situation. 
Will proceed accordingly.

Comment: One last comment. This summer Google is tightening down security for applications that allow users to access Google Cloud APIs. In summary, Google does not want applications that run in a browser to access those APIs. This is simply a security compliance issue. Getting approval is possible but might require an expensive third-party security audit. In my last document link, read the section titled `Security Assessment`.

Comment: Is there any library / documentation for implementing backend service account authorisation? I am reading through the documents but don't seem to find an example 

Other colleagues have created a service account credentials for me, yet since I wasn't the one that created it, I did not get the `json` key file, I will have to solve that as well. 
I found a template of the json key format here 
[Service Key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete#iam-service-account-keys-create-gcloud)

@JohnHanley

Comment: Using service accounts is the standard method so all the documentation shows that. Search for ADC (Application Default Credentials). All of the services have SDK examples using service accounts. Note: you do not need to know the format of the JSON key. The SDK methods know how to read that file.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by @John Hanley, Since you're unable to use backend at the moment you can make use of Google user OAuth .
For the OAuth 2.0 flow, you can follow [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#example) google documentation.
However, it is advisable to use service accounts for authorization which can be easily done from backend code.
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Comment: Is there any library / documentation for implementing backend service account authorisation? 

I am reading through the documents but don't seem to find an example